# How to set PowerPoint version in PowerPoint C++ automation?

Tags: c++, automation, mfc, powerpoint

I am using MFC,PowerPoint2003&2010 C++ automation,in Windows 10.

There are PowerPoint2003 and PowerPoint2010 in my computer.

My code is:

```
// Firstly,I load PowerPoint2003 and PowerPoint2010 c++ automation library
// Start the powerpoint in Powerpoint2003 automation
CApplication app2003;
if(!app2003.CreateDispatch(_T("Powerpoint.Application.11")))
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Couldn't start PowerPoint."));
}
else // Make PowerPoint visible 
{
    app2003.put_Visible(TRUE);
}
...
// close the powerpoint

// Start the powerpoint in PowerPoint2010 automation
CApplication0 app2010;   // CApplication0 is powerpoint2010 automation class
if(!app2010.CreateDispatch(_T("Powerpoint.Application.14")))
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Couldn't start PowerPoint."));
}
else // Make PowerPoint visible 
{
    app2010.put_Visible(TRUE);
}
...
// close the powerpoint
```

I load the type library from **MSPPT.OLB** in Office14 directory.

An overview of CApplication is following：
[image]
However,when I run the code, the PowerPoint versions are both PowerPoint2010.

My question is：

How can I control the c++ automation to open specific PowerPoint version?

Comment: `CApplication` is not a standard MFC class (not in new VS versions anyway). Provide links if possible.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani  I reedit my question.